Error handling using Firebase SDK functions in React
I'm using Firebase SDK functions to get and post data. But when I'm receiving an error from the backend I'm not able to catch it. The error sent from backend shows up in the networks but the error that I'm catching is not capturing the details sent from the backend. How do I fix this?
`
const saveKey = async () => { 
    const payload = getPayload();    
    try {
            const result = await createKeyFunction({
                functionName: 'testName',
                payload: payload,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('error test==>>', error);
    }
};`

The error that I'm catching is:
code: "functions/internal"
customData: undefined
details: undefined
name: "FirebaseError"
message: "internal"
stack: "FirebaseError: internal"

The error that I'm getting from the backend is:
additionalInfo: {error: "AddSecurity is not implemented"}
code: "invalid-argument"
details: {error: "AddSecurity is not implemented"}
message: "AddSecurity is not implemented"


I found the solution. The error needs to be in the format mentioned below:
{

    error: {
     details: {code: "", message: "AddSecurity is not implemented"} 
    }
}

